# Ionic Function defined in services.js and called in controller.js is not executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, controller, ionic-framework

I have this service defined in services.js with a very simple function:

```
.service('CheckLoginService', function ($q, $http){
  var LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY = 'yourTokenKey';
  var loadUser = '';

  function loadUserCredentials () {
  //loadUser = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
    loadUser = 'pippo';
  }

  return {
    loadUserCredentials: loadUser
  };

})
```

I'm calling this function from this code in controller.js

```
.controller('BeforeloginCtrl', function($state, $scope, $ionicPopup, CheckLoginService) {
    $scope.check = function() {
        var checkUser = CheckLoginService.loadUserCredentials();
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'check!',
          template: checkUser
        });
        if(checkUser !== '') {
            $state.go('tab.dash');
        } else {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    }
})
```

The controller is set in the app.js app first page, but when I emulate my app nothing happens: no matter what the value of checkUser, neither it routes to any of the pages called in the `$state.go()` nor the popup appears, so I'm guessing that the function `loadUserCredentials()` is never called.

The emulator does not return any error.

**UPDATE**: even trying to execute the code directly in controller.js, the result is the same: nothing happens

```
.controller('BeforeloginCtrl', function($state, $scope, $ionicPopup, CheckLoginService) {
    function check() {
//      var checkUser = CheckLoginService.loadUserCredentials();
//      var checkUser = window.localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY);
        var checkUser = '';
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'check!',
          template: checkUser
        });
        if(checkUser != '') {
            $state.go('tab.dash');
        } else {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    }
    $scope.check = check;
});
```

Anybody who can explain this behaviour?

Comment: Hi @Alexander, thanks for your prompt answer, unfortunately even with .factory it still does not work...

Comment: From what you're showing, you're not actually ever calling the check function.  In your update version, you can call the private function check by adding: check(); or in the original controller, you can use $scope.check();

Comment: @SteveRoss if there is a complete tutorial article of this question, would you please give the link?